# Looking for a logic game 5 people 5 cities

Tags: logic-grid, puzzle-identification

I am looking for a logic game where there are 5 people and 5 cities. They have to travel around the 5 cities but in each city there can only be one person. They move around but they can never be in the same city. I used to use it with my kids but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: This sounds a bit like [**Einstein's Riddle**](https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/einsteins-riddle/). If only the cities were *houses*.

Comment: Is it a puzzle or a game? If the latter, you might have more luck at our sister site [boardgames.se].

Comment: If you want to find that specific puzzle in the haystack of hundreds of similar grid puzzles, you need some differentiating information, such as the names of cities. Was there a time element in the puzzle? For example, "Sally was not in Chicago on Tuesday."